# Java Math like classes in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How we can create `Java` Math like Util classes in `Kotlin`. So that I can call something like `Math.add()`.
I try to do using companion object. Let me know if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Consider using top-level function without an explicit class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use a simple [`object` declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) to achieve that syntax:

```
object Math {
    fun add(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
}
```

This creates a singleton class, with only one instance at runtime, and you can call the methods on this instance with the `Math.add(1, 4)` syntax.

---

Companion objects are just special cases of these `object` declarations nested inside classes, with their members accessible through the container class's identifier, similarly to static functions in Java.

You can actually nest any object inside a class, the `companion` keyword just lets you create them without an explicit name.

Example of named nested objects:

```
class A {
    fun a() {}
    object B {
        fun b() {}
    }
    companion object {
        fun o() {}
    }
}
```

These functions can then be called like this:

```
A().a()          // this call of course needs an instance of A
A.B.b()
A.Companion.o()
A.o()
```

Comment: out of above two ways, which one is best considering my requirements.

Comment: I don't think you need a companion object here at all, you can just use a regular one. If you need to call these functions from Java too, you can still annotate them with [`@JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/), just like in a companion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like

```
    class Math {
        companion object {
            fun add(val x: Int, val y: Int): Int {
                return x+y
            }
            fun subtract(val x: Int, val y: Int): Int {
                return x-y
            }
            fun multiply(val x: Int, val y: Int): Int {
                return x*y
            }
            ...
        }
     }
```

Comment: What is the benefit of putting this object inside another class? Can't it work on its own?

Comment: As you have asked for Math.add() that's why it's is being placed inside Math class else it can work.